# Why does having static members make a language less object-orientated?

Tags: java, scala

I'm learning Scala at the moment and I came across this statement in Odersky's Programming Scala 2nd edition:

> one way in which Scala is more object-orientated than Java is that classes in Scala  cannot have static members.

I'm not sufficiently experienced in either Java or Scala to understand that comparison. Why does having static members make a language less OO?

Comment: I'm replying to all your answers here. So basically what you are all saying is that in order to be a pure OO language, the language must always operate on objects (ie the class must be instantiated). If I am allowed to invoke aspects of a class without instantiating it, this goes against pure OO-theory?

Comment: Don't reply to answers like this. This won't notify anyone so they won't know to check.

Comment: @I.K.  I think we're saying that's what we think Odersky thinks, though some of us may disagree.  Ultimately, this topic is pretty much opinion based.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Odersky's statement is valid and significant, but some people don't understand what he meant.

Let's say that in Java you have a class Foo with method f:

```
class Foo {
  int f() { /* does something great */ }
}
```

You can write a method that takes a Foo and invokes f on it:

```
void g(Foo foo) { foo.f(); }
```

Perhaps there is a class SubFoo that extends Foo; g works on that too.  There can be a whole set of classes, related by inheritance or by an interface, which share the fact that they can be used with g.

Now let's make that f method *static*:

```
class Foo {
  static int f() { /* does something great */ }
}
```

Can we use this new Foo with g, perhaps like so?

```
g(Foo);  // No, this is nonsense.
```

Darn.  OK, let's change the signature of g so that we can pass Foo to it and have it invoke f.

Ooops -- we can't.  We can't pass around a reference to Foo because **Foo is not an instance of some class**.  Some people commenting here are confused by the fact that there is a Class object corresponding to Foo, but as Sotirios tried to explain, that Class object does not have an f method and Foo is not an instance of that class.  Foo is not an instance of anything; it is not an object at all.  The Class object for Foo is an instance of class Class that has information about Foo (think of it as Foo's internal Wikipedia page), and is *completely irrelevant* to the discussion.  The Wikipedia page for "tiger" is not a tiger.

In Java, "primitives" like 3 and 'x' are not objects.  They *are* objects in Scala.  For performance your program will use JVM primitives for 3 and 'x' wherever possible during execution, but at the level you code in they really are objects.  The fact that they are *not* objects in Java has rather unfortunate consequences for anyone trying to write code that handles all data types -- you have to have special logic and additional methods to cover primitives.  If you've ever seen or written that kind of code, you know that it's awful.  Odersky's statement is not "purism"; far from it.

In Scala there is no piece of runtime data that is not an object, and there is no thing you can invoke methods on that is not an object.  In Java neither of these statements in true; Java is a partially object-oriented language.  In Java there are things which are not objects and there are methods which aren't on objects.

Newcomers to Scala often think of `object Foo` as some weird replacement for Java statics, but that's something you need to get past quickly. Instead think of Java's static methods as a non-OO wart and Scala's `object Foo { ... }` as something along these lines:

```
class SomeHiddenClass { ... }
val Foo = new SomeHiddenClass  // the only instance of it
```

Here Foo is a *value*, not a *type*, and it really is an object.  It can be passed to a method.  It can extend some other class.  For example:

```
abstract class AbFoo { def f:Int }
object Foo extends AbFoo { def f = 2 }
```

Now, finally, you can say

```
g(Foo)
```

It is true that a "companion object" for a class is a good place to put non-instance methods and data for the class.  But that companion object is an object, so the usual rules and capabilities apply.

The fact that in Java you put such methods on non-objects -- limiting how they can be used -- is a liability, not a feature.  It is certainly *not* OO.

Comment: I understand why Prof. Odersky said what he said now. Great post.

Comment: Surely this is the best answer, esp the last part supplemented by Mr J Mittag's midday answer. That's the reply to Warren Dew's counter-argument. Hoping the green check defects.

Comment: Agreed, because I wanted to know why Prof. Odersky claims that Scala is more of an OO language than Java. This post explains it whereas the other posts just explained generally why static methods make a language less OO.

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure I completely buy that argument, but here is one possible reasoning.

To an object-oriented purist, everything should be an object, and all state should be encapsulated by objects. Any `static` member of a class is by definition state which exists *outside of an object*, because you can use it and manipulate it without instantiating an object. Thus, the lack of static class members makes for a more pure object-oriented language.

Comment: I agree that this is probably the reasoning behind the argument.  In Java, though, classes are objects, so in my opinion the argument is bogus.

Comment: @WarrenDew, This is pretty much pure speculation on our parts. :P

Comment: @Warren Careful, Java classes have a corresponding `Class` object but that is not in the least involved when invoking a static method.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis You cannot call static methods until the class object has been loaded into memory by the classloader.

Comment: @Warren Sure, but that isn't relevant. The static method is not invoked on the `Class` object nor does it affect any of its state. In any sense of the terms OOP, the two are completely unrelated.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I disagree.  From an implementation standpoint, the method is invoked on the class object, even if there is specialized syntax for doing so.  In many cases, the state of the class object - for example, static data members - will also be affected.  The two may be unrelated in your sense of the term OOP, but they are related in my sense of the term.

Comment: @I.K., I can't say I care about the professor's thoughts; it's like saying - laced shoes are more foot-oriented than velcro ones (aka, fan-boy stuff). It's not profound or bold either; it's very matter-of-fact. No object - no object-orientation.

Comment: @WarrenDew this is about the nature of the language, not its implementation.  The fact that you can't call static methods until the class object is available in the classloader is simply the workings of a JVM; not a characteristic of the Java language itself.

Comment: "From an implementation standpoint, the method is invoked on the class object, even if there is specialized syntax for doing so." No. Look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.invokestatic, the class object isn't involved in the same way as when calling instance methods.

Answer (score 1):

Well, with static members like methods you don't have any objects to create and nevertheless you can call such static methods. You only need the static classname in order to set the namespace for these methods, for example:

```
long timeNow = System.currentTimeMillis(); // no object creation
```

This rather gives a feeling like in procedural languages.

Answer (score 1):

static members belongs to the Class not to the object while the main concept of oop lies among the relation between the individual objects of dirrefer Class.

Answer (score 1):

A `static` method in Java is one that operates on the class itself, and doesn't need an Object to be created first. For example, this line:

```
int c = Integer.parseInt("5");
```

`Integer.parseInt()` is static because I didn't have to go `Integer i = new Integer();` before using it; this isn't operating on any particular object that I've created, since it's always going to be the same, and is more like a typical procedural function call instead of an object-oriented method. It's more object-oriented if I have to create an object for every call and we encapsulate everything that way instead of allowing `static` to use methods as faux-procedural-functions.

Answer (score 1):

There are several competing definitions of what *exactly* object-orientation means. However, there is one thing they all can agree on: dynamic dispatch is a fundamental part of the definition of OO.

Static methods are static (duh), not dynamic, ergo they are *by definition* not object-oriented.

And logically, a language that has a feature which isn't object-oriented is in some sense "less OO" than a language which doesn't have said feature.

Comment: Yes, this is what everyone else is saying. But what I need to know is why Scala is more of an OO language than java. To me, with my current level of knowledge of Scala, all Prof. Odersky did was take out the static members from class definitions and put them in the companion object. The class and companion object can still reference each other's private members. It's just a different way of doing the same thing. So to me it seems that scala is not more OO than Java and vice versa. Maybe I am wrong?