# Why does Scala starts from an object's main method instead of a class's static main method?

Tags: java, scala, oop, object

In Java, a program starts from a class's static main method. But in Scala, it starts from a object's main method.

Does anyone know the rationality of designing like this?

Scala also provide a trait called `App`, which can replace `main` method if an object extends this trait. Does anyone have ideas about which one (`App` or `main`) is the preferred way?

Thanks!

Comment: Objects are static, so objects can be main methods. Objects' methods are static, so objects' methods can be main methods.

Comment: @RyoichiroOka objects are not static. They are singletons, which mean there is a real instance of it and it can be passed around as any other object.

Comment: @roterl sorry i used the term "static" in much wider sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using static is like using global functions. Scala is pure object oriented language and has no statics. But in fact Scala compiler generates static main for JVM.
It is recommended to use 'App' trait for short study programs.

Comment: Why just "for short study programs"?  I am not aware of any drawback to using App versus writing an explicit main method.

Answer (score 7):

Scala has singleton objects instead of java static members. So main method of object is analogue of java static main method.

Answer (score 4):

I always extend `App` in my main class, and know of no reason why anyone would want to write an explicit main method -- except possibly to be compatible with some other code that was overly fussy about such things.  Whenever I see an explicit main method in Scala, I wonder whether the code is very old (predating the `App` trait) or the author was new to Scala.

But this question appears to largely be about why the designers of Scala omitted static methods.  You may find [this question about how static members are not object-oriented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22890024/why-does-having-static-members-make-a-language-less-object-orientated) helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Scala doesn't have static methods. If Scala required starting programs from a static main method, then you could never run a Scala program, because you couldn't write a static main method.